# Why is the "Load putty key" field in TortoiseGit disabled?

Tags: git, putty, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

I would like to connect to my repository using an SSH key instead of a username & password.

However when I try to do this in TortoiseGit I can not enter the key because the "Load Putty Key" is disabled. Can anyone point out why this is happening and how I can enable the field?

Comment: Hi Mihir, you can re-accept an answer by unchecking and checking the other answer. [mirancon answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15486019/1326147) really helped, unlike Lazy's one-line-answer and broken link...

Comment: @Armfoot Done! , Link is now broken, but it was working at that time :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In TortoiseGit settings go to *Network*. In field *SSH Client*, specify the path to TortoiseGitPLink

e.g.:

> C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe

Comment: Truly appreciated :) This was driving me nuts... I uninstalled both git and tortoisegit and reversed the installation order (tortoisegit first and git after). In the step of choosing Open SSH or Plink in git's installation, this path: `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe` was auto-filled for Plink. However even choosing Plink, the SSH client option you mentioned in tortoisegit>Network tab had `ssh.exe` instead of that path... Changing according to what you suggested solved it.

Comment: For clarity's sake, you put the PLink path into the "SSH Client" field in the Network settings.

Comment: When I do this, TortoiseGit does nothing when I click OK. It does not save the value. There is no error message.

Answer (score 8):

Setting correct path to `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` for `SSH client:` in `Settings->Network` should fix the problem.  Something like:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe
```

**BUT, in some cases the new path is not saved for some reason!**

As mentioned in the comments, sometimes (in my case `TortoiseGit 2.5.0.0`) the setting was not being applied.  Clicking on `OK` or `Apply` was not producing any error, but when closing and opening the `Settings` again, the old path was there.

In order to workaround this, check also `Enable Proxy Server` in the same `Network` menu (do not provide any proxy settings).  After this the window will close on `OK` press, and when reopened, `Enable Proxy Server` will be unchecked, but the new path will be saved.

Comment: Please upgrade TortoiseGit to 2.6.0.

Comment: @YueLinHo, that's not always possible.  Sometimes you have to stick to versions approved within an organization.

Comment: FYI, "The settings is not saved" is a known TortoiseGit issue and got fixed.

Answer (score 4):

SSH and key based authentification is a job of SSH-client (plink) and key-agent (pageant)

Comment: can you guide me by explaining the procedure please?

Comment: [TortoiseGit Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_CentralServerWindowsXP) in chapter "On The Client" - "Configuration procedure"

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to fix this issue, please follow the picture. thanks

[image]